# WPF application search for updates

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF application developed in Visual Studio 2013 C#.

I am using Installshield 2014 Pro for installation .exe production.

I want the application to search for updates in my website and locate the new version in it.

Can I do it in code behind or do I need external software?

Is there any free tool to do it?

Comment: The simplest way is probably having a version file in the server, then downloading it with your code, parsing the version contained within and comparing it to the current one. If it's "greater", download the program's file next.

Comment: what is version file and how can i implement it in my code? do you have an example?

Comment: The [Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class helps deal with version numbers you may want to compare or parse from a text file, such as "1.0.5.24".

Comment: do you have example for code implementation?

Comment: how can i compare between application version and site last version?

Comment: @user281812 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion%28v=vs.110%29.aspx